# start spark remote metastore -- Hive from spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-1.3

I am trying to use remote metastore when using spark sql

--> using spark 1.3.1

--> copied hive-site.xml from hive/conf to spark/conf

--> using mysql remote metastore

--> added mysql jar to commute-classpath.sh and lib

when starting spark-sql getting:

```
  2015-07-27 12:08:50 INFO  metastore:297 - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://192.168.145.45:9083 
  2015-07-27 12:08:50 WARN  metastore:344 - Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server..
```

In hive we cn start with hive --service metastore

HOW does spark start remote metastore???

Comment: Spark doesn't supposed to start remote metastore service. You should have the metastore service already running on the remote server and spark will connect to it. You should check if the service is running and if your spark server have access to metastore server and port.